# CheckBox vs CheckedTextView in a ListView

Tags: java, android

When I place a `CheckBox` in the row layout for a `ListView`, I am no longer able to recieve `OnItemClick` and `OnItemLongClick` events. On the other hand, using `CheckedTextView` allows these events to go through, but I don't know how to automate clicking on them in my JUnit/Robotium tests. Does anyone have any suggestions about what I can do to get the best of both worlds here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make OnItem(Long)Click work if you set up the `CheckBox` views to non-focusable (i.e. `setFocusable(false)` and `setFocusableInTouchMode(false)`, or their xml equivalents).

Note: The listeners will fire as long as you tap outside the checkbox itself. Tapping on the checkbox will toggle it only (but I guess this is what you would want).

Comment: Will this still allow the checkbox to be checked?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, but I'll add a detail to the answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You're welcome. It makes you feel really proud to be thanked by high-rep users ;)